# Not clear on one attribute value in shorthand version of background property?

Tags: css

```
background: url(/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/TwAHgQi2ZPB.png) 0 bottom repeat-x;
```

Can anyone tell what the 0 specifies in above property's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the below screenshot, the 0 refers to the `background-position`. A unit need not be provided if the value is 0 and the browser automatically assigns the unit to it.

To be more precise it refers to X coordinate of the `background-position` or `background-position-x`.

**Screenshot from Chrome's Dev Console:**

[image]

**Screenshot from Firefox's Dev Console:**

[image]

**Screenshot from Edge's Dev Console:**

[image]